# Controller keeps generating SQL query with wrong foreign key name

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have a database tables Users, Listings
Users table:

```
id, name, email, password
```

Listings table:

```
id, title, seller_id
```

Listing migration:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('listings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->bigInteger('seller_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('seller_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

User model:

```
public function listings()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Listing::class);
    }
```

Listing model:

```
public function seller()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'seller_id', 'id');
    }
```

ListingResource:

```
namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class ListingResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return parent::toArray($request);
    }
}
```

ListingsController:

```
public function index()
    {
        return ListingResource::collection(auth()->user()->listings()->latest());
    }
```

I keep getting this error:

"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'listings.user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `listings` where `listings`.`user_id` = 1 and `listings`.`user_id` is not null order by `created_at` desc limit 1)"

How come it returns the query with user_id as the foreign key, even though I specifically put 'seller_id' as the foreign key inside the User.php model?

I have tried to put:

```
    public function listings()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Listing::class, 'seller_id');
    }
```

As I have read that this could work, but this generates the following error:

"Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::mapInto()"

Comment: check this post for your last error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47710805/laravel-api-resource-call-to-undefined-method-illuminate-database-query-builder

Comment: Does it work if you do `auth()->user()->listings()->latest()->get()`? `->latest()` doesn't actually execute the query; it's shorthand for `->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')`, so you've got a `Builder` instance instead of a `Collection` at that point.

Comment: @TimLewis shoot. I missed that small detail. This resolved this issue for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the error message isn't the most clear for this, what is essentially happening is that `{Resource}::collection($collection);` requires a `Collection` to function, but at the current point in it's lifecycle, your argument is a `Builder` instance. To fix this, simply pass a `closure` to convert your `Builder` to a `Collection`:

```
public function index(){
    return ListingResource::collection(auth()->user()->listings()->latest()->get());
}
```

`->latest()` is shorthand for `->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');` (or `id`, not sure which it uses internally), but doesn't actually execute the query. Simply adding `->get()` will convert the `Builder` to a `Collection` and allow this resource to work.

On another note, the original error was being caused by missing `seller_id` in your `listings()` function on your `User` model. The foreign id of any relationship is guessed by Laravel based on the Model name (`User` translates to `user_id`), but since you're using `seller_id`, you need to specify that in both the original relationship and in the inverse definition. You figured that out, but a quick explanation is always helpful.